# В чем разница между хотеть что-то не делать и не хотеть что-то делать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В чем разница между хотеть что-то **не** делать и **не** хотеть что-то делать?

Comment: Можно заменить на следующее, чтоб звучало: *он хочет, чтоб не надо было работать; он не хочет, чтоб надо было работать*.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, следует отметить, что зачастую, когда люди говорят ‟я не хочу делать это”, они обозначают не отсутствие желания, а чувство отторжения. Например, в предложении: ‟Я не хочу делать домашнее задание”. Еще пример: когда дети говорят: ‟Я не хочу убираться в комнате”, то они обозначают не отсутствие желания, а чувство отторжения. В предложениях же: ‟Может сходим в кино?” — ‟Я не хочу идти в кино” — обозначается не чувство отторжения, а уже отсутствие желания. Я буду рассматривать именно случаи с наличием и отсутствием желания.
Если человек скажет: ‟Я хочу идти не в кино”, то это бессмыслица, так как нельзя хотеть чего-то всего, кроме этого. Это предложение буквально значит, что человек хочет идти куда угодно, кроме кинотеатра. Такое предложение может быть только как противопоставление: ‟Я хочу идти не в кино, а в театр”. Также, возможно, такое предложение может быть неким фигуральным приёмом.

Comment: ‟Я хочу идти не в кино” не равно ‟Я хочу не идти в кино”.

Comment: Ну да. К предложению: ‟Я хочу не идти в кино” — такие же претензии, как к предложению: ‟Я хочу идти не в кино”.

Answer (score 1):

> Хотеть что-то не делать

Подразумевает желание не делать, отказаться от работы, отказаться от текущей работы в угоду отказу от работы

> Не хотеть что-то делать

Подразумевает отсутствие желания делать хоть что-то, не браться за работу, продолжать делать ничего

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно такая же как и в случаях привлечения к ответственности  за не оказание помощи. Впрочем возможно что не хотевший помоч был уверен что своими силами помощи (не обходимой в конкретной ситуации) оказать не в состоянии

Comment: 1. «УК РФ Статья 124. **Неоказание** помощи больному». 2. Необходимой = нужной. 3. В конце предложения ставят точку, а здесь и запятых нет. 4. Нет такого слова «помоч».

Comment: Iногда встъчается в лiтературе определенiе "буквоъдство".  ;)  с Вашей то дотошностiю, не моглiбъ дать нам опредъленiе? Ну вроде как в Вiкiпъдiи? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Сразу ответ. **Разница в общем-то есть или может может быть. Но однозначно сказать, в чем именно она состоит, нельзя.** Слишком много ситуаций и слишком много вариантов понимания той и другой конструкции.

И сразу замечу, что многие языке не видят разницы между двумя подобными высказываниями, или выбор определяется просто грамматикой. Но это не наш случай.

Если же говорить о семантической разнице высказываний (а никакую другую я просто не хочу на этом ресурсе рассматривать), то она есть и во многом, если не во всем, определяется контекстом. Причем сильно зависит от того, что именно "делать" / "не делать" предстоит действующему объекту.

"Хотеть" здесь выступает в модальном значении, а все модальные глаголы в русском в той или иной степени - многозначны. Отсюда и возможности разного понимания.

Даже если "делать" - собственно глагол, сказуемое, а не его обозначение, то уже возникают варианты понимания.

Рассмотрим утвердительное предложение.
***"Я хочу что-то делать"*** - именно в таком виде. Оно может означать, например, что "Я" (лирический герой) - скучает, и хочет чем-то себя занять.
В этом случае отрицание может звучать так: ***"Я не хочу что-то (чего-то) делать"*** - оно означает, например, что говорящий устал - и ему не до каких-то вообще занятий.

Конструкция ***"я хочу чего-то не делать"*** в данном случае просто неприменима, поскольку означает нежелание "делать" не вообще всё, а "что-то" конкретное, по каким-то причинам не называемое явно.
В общем-то уже достаточно, чтобы аргументировать утверждение о разнице конструкций.

Если же мы начнем подставлять конкретные глаголы и объекты вместо "делать" и "что-то", то вариантов будет просто необозримое множество, и, как сказал, не в последнюю очередь из-за многозначности глагола "хотеть".

***Я не хочу есть*** - я не голоден.
***Я хочу не есть*** - я решил подавить чувство голода (на какое-то время).

***Я не хочу его видеть*** - не до него мне сейчас
***Я хочу его не видеть*** - он мне противен (как вариант)

***Я не хочу идти в армию*** - желание "откосить"
***Я хочу не идти в армию...*** - а чего-то там еще.

Что можно заметить? Прямому отрицанию более соответствует вариант с "не" перед "хочу". "Не" перед "делать" обычно придает несколько изощренный смысл, которая в утвердительной форме потребовал бы дополнительных лексических средств.
Но это тоже не абсолют:

***Я не хочу спать один*** - человек страдает от одиночества.
(из фильма какого-то ненашего).
***Я хочу не спать один*** - когда я одинок, мне не спится.

И я совсем не уверен, какая из этих двух конструкций является отрицанием для утверждения ***"я хочу спать один"***. По мне так именно вторая.
*Я умышленно оставил именно этот, возможно спорный, пример ради демонстрации того, как много может определять контекст.*

**Короче, на ваш вопрос просто невозможно дать объективно верный ответ. Тем более - "канонический", как бы вам того не хотелось.**